# Unable to build for Ad Hoc using Xcode

Tags: xcode

I have an app that builds and runs just fine on either the device or simulator.  I want to send it to a friend to test, but I can't seem to build using the Ad Hoc provisioning profile.  The profile was created and moved to the Xcode icon on the tray...  The provisioning profile appears in Xcode Organizer.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry but on my side is not clear what kind of error was thrown by the compiler. Can you post the output?

Comment: For starters, the only "active" configurations are: Debug and Release... Ad Hoc isn't shown, therefore, I can't build for it.

Comment: Ok. AdHoc build essentially is a Release build made to test the app in a "release environment" with some specific devices before the submission. Set your target as Release then, in the "Code Signing Identity" field, choose your AdHoc provisioning from the list. It should work.

Comment: Don't see "Code Signing Identity" field... where is it?

Comment: In the Group & Files sidebar, command+I on your project icon to access the project info. Click on the "build" tab. In the "Configuration" dropdown, select "Release". In the search field on the right, search for "Code Signing". You should see some fields. For the "Any iOS" field, on the right dropdown, select your provisioning profile name (should be hilighted in black and bold).

Comment: Useful link: http://blog.futureshock-ed.com/2011/01/ios-ad-hock-app-distribution-for-beta.html that explain how to build an AdHoc release for beta testing.

Comment: Thank you...got by that one... now I'm getting this:

Code Sign error: Provisioning profile 'Points Ad Hoc' specifies the Application Identifier 'com.pragerphoneapps.PointsEncodeDecode' which doesn't match the current setting 'com.yourcompany.PointsEncodeDecode'

I did a search for "yourcompany" but found nothing, so I don't know where it's coming from...

Comment: Your link to futureshock has instructions that I didn't even know about (I have been using MonoTouch, which does most of this for you; unfortunately, I didn't learn Obj-C, and so I decided to start back at square one).  

Let me go through the doc and I'll get back to you if I need more help.  Thanks so much for your help so far... I appreciate it.

Comment: You're welcome. To solve the last issue posted, edit your Info.plist file (should be in your Resources group). Change the "Bundle identifier" according to your AdHoc profile (just replace "yourcompany" with "pragerphoneapps". Hope this helps. Ciao!

Comment: Wonderful... thank you so much... I really appreciate it!

One more question:  I notice that the provisioning profile filename is made up of a bunch of numbers, followed by "mobileprovision".  Can I safely rename the filename to something more meaningful without messing up the whole works?

Comment: If you're not so familiar with "x-code stuff", it would be better to keep those files as they are. When you imported your .mobileprovision into your library, it has been copied into a default directory and renamed with a unique 
name to avoid conflicts (I guess). Anyway, you may also manage your provisioning profiles library with the Organizer (x-code > window > organizer) that show you the friendly name. Ciao!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lomanf gave me the correct answers; unfortunately he/she did not set them up as answers, so I will do it for him/her.  Thank you so much for your help.